# How to calculate total Sum of all column cells in a table?

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

I'm collecting my API data in an array list `List<GetTestFeeMap> reponseArray =[];   // Storing API response`

and Adding new data to my array every time I'm calling my API, then use map function to construct my dynamic table.

**Now I'm trying to calculate total SUM of the column and display it** (not necessarily in table).

Hope you understood my problem.

[image]

```
  Future<void> GetTestFee() async {
var jsonResponse;
if (encTestId.isNotEmpty) {
  var response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse("http://gtyuigetvytun/api/medboapi/GetTestFee"),
      body: ({
        'EncPartnerId': encLabId,
        'EncTestId': encTestId,

      }));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print("Correct");
    print(response.body);
    jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body.toString());
    print(jsonResponse);
    getTestFeeObj=GetTestFeeMap.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    setState(() {
      reponseArray.add(getTestFeeObj!); // Adding data to my Arraylist
        for(GetTestFeeMap elem in reponseArray){
              feeSum += elem.fee as int;
              discountSum += elem.discountedFee as int; // Doing calculation here
              bookingSum += elem.bookingFee as int;
            }
            print(feeSum);
            print(discountSum);
            print(discountSum);
    });

  }
```

Then creating my dynamic table using ArrayList of data

```
 DataTable(
               columnSpacing: 13.0,
                columns: <DataColumn>[
                  DataColumn(label: Text("Fee")),
                  DataColumn(label: Text("Discounted Fee")),
                  DataColumn(label: Text("Booking Fee")),
                ],
                
                 rows:reponseArray.map((testRowData){
                  return DataRow(
                    cells: [
                      DataCell(Text(testRowData.fee ?? '')),
                      DataCell(Text(testRowData.discountedFee ?? '')),
                      DataCell(Text(testRowData.bookingFee ?? ''))
                    ]
                  );
                }).toList()
            ),
```

Comment: What is that you don't know? You calculate sum like this: int sum = 0; for (...) { sum += value;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go through your `responseArray` items and keep track of three sums

```
int feeSum = 0;
int discountSum = 0;
int bookingSum = 0;

for(GetTestFeeMap elem in reponseArray){
  feeSum += elem.fee;
  discountSum += elem.discountedFee;
  bookingSum += elem.bookingFee;
}
```

Comment: I put the `for loop` in my API function `setState(){}` and for now just trying to print in console to check whether the implementation is correct or not. Unfortunately Exxception occurred  `Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast`

Comment: As `reponseArray` items are arrayList item I believe they are in `String` format thats why it is not calculate the sum?  By making `String feeSum = ""` displaying me Addition as Sting value `(500300)` somthing like this

Comment: You should probably change your class definition by replacing `String? fee;` by `int? fee;`  And if your API returns string you can edit your `fromJson` method changing `fee = json['Fee'];` into `fee = int.parse(json['Fee']);`

Comment: Got it . But instead of giving `800` (ex: for 1st column)  its give me `1300` .. This expression of yours also logically correct `feeSum += elem.fee as int;` So why it is calculating like `(500+500+300)=1300` ? [ https://pastebin.com/tsj7Wkhc ]

Comment: First api call==> `500` to my ArrayList ||  Second Api call==> `300` to my ArrayList. From where its getting extra `500` ?

Comment: By resetting  `feeSum=0` befor my loop start works. Thanks for your time